# Particle Physics weight diagram in LaTeX Help!

Tags: physics

I am writing a paper and I need to find the way to code these diagrams in LaTeX. I made those in Photoshop, but when I upload them in overleaf they lose quality . . .

I have been looking for similar diagrams in arxiv.org to copy them from the source files but I haven't had luck :/

Any help will be helpful, thank you !!!

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you exactly mean by that ?

Comment: I was just welcoming you on the site. I'm confident you'll get help soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is another approach that is similar to Ignasi's in that I also use [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz), however, it is different in that I define a macro `\WeightDiagram` for drawing the weight diagrams. This macro takes an arbitrary number of "weights" which it is assumed will be typeset in mathematics-mode. For example,

```
\WeightDiagram{\sum^{++}_c, \sum^+_c, \sum^0_c}
```

produces

[image]

Given this, the table is drawn by putting the different weight diagrams into a tabular environment. For the first table (the second table is a minor variation) this produces:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\WeightDiagram[1]{%
  \tikz{\foreach \diag [count=\D, remember=\D as \lastD (initially 0)] in {#1} {%
          \draw[fill] (\D,0) circle[radius=2pt]node[above=1mm]{$\diag$};%
          \ifnum\lastD>0\draw[thick](\lastD,0)--(\D,0);\fi%
        }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
  \[
    \begin{array}{cc@{}c@{}c}
                 &  (6,\frac12^+) & & (6,\frac32^+)\\
       I=1       & \WeightDiagram{\sum^{++}_c, \sum^+_c, \sum^0_c}&
                 & \WeightDiagram{\sum^{++}_b, \sum^+_b, \sum^0_b}\\
       I=\frac12 & \WeightDiagram{\Xi^{+\prime}_c,\Xi^{0\prime}_c}
                 & (\overline{3},\frac12^+)
                 & \WeightDiagram{\Xi^+_c,\Xi^0_c}\\
       I=0       & \WeightDiagram{\Omega^0_c}
                 & \WeightDiagram{\Lambda^+_c}
                 & \WeightDiagram{\Omega^0_c}\\
       I=-\frac12& & \WeightDiagram{\Xi^+_c, \Xi^0_c}
    \end{array}
  \]


\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a more compact and clear version of what I want to represent. Thanks !!

Comment: The isospins of Xi belonging to the triplet are 1/2, since it's not the 3rd component but the total Isospin, but I will fix that later. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 7):

You can start with:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    dot/.style={circle, fill, inner sep=1pt}
    ]

\node[dot, label={$\Sigma_c^{++}$}] (11) {}; 
\node[dot, label={$\Sigma_c^{+}$}, right=of 11] (12) {}; \node[dot, label={$\Sigma_c^{0}$}, right=of 12] (13) {};
\draw (11)--(13);
\node[above=.75cm of 12] {$(6,\frac{1}{2}^+)$};

\node[dot, label={$\Sigma_c^{++}$}, right=of 13] (14) {}; 
\node[dot, label={$\Sigma_c^{+}$}, right=of 14] (15) {}; \node[dot, label={$\Sigma_c^{0}$}, right=of 15] (16) {};
\draw (14)--(16);
\node[above=.75cm of 15] {$(6,\frac{3}{2}^+)$};

\node[dot, label={$\Xi_c^{+'}$}, below right= 1cm and 5mm of 11] (21) {}; 
\node[dot, label={$\Xi_c^{0'}$}, right=of 21] (22) {}; 
\draw (21)--(22);

\node[dot, label={$\Xi_c^{+}$}, below right= 1cm and 5mm of 14] (23) {}; 
\node[dot, label={$\Xi_c^{0}$}, right=of 23] (24) {}; 
\draw (23)--(24);

\node[dot, label={$\Omega_c^{0}$}, below right= 1cm and 5mm of 21] (31) {}; 
\node[dot, label={$\Omega_c^{0}$}, below right= 1cm and 5mm of 23] (33) {}; 
\path (31) -- node[dot, label={$\Lambda_c^{+}$}] (32) {} (33); 
\node[above=.75cm of 32] {$(\overline{3},\frac{1}{2}^+)$};

\node[dot, label={$\Xi_c^{+}$}, below left= 1cm and 5mm of 32] (41) {}; 
\node[dot, label={$\Xi_c^{0}$}, below right= 1cm and 5mm of 32] (42) {}; 
\draw (41)--(42);

\node[left= 3mm of 11] (1) {$I=1$};
\node at (1|-21) {$I=\frac{1}{2}$};
\node at (1|-31) {$I=0$};
\node at (1|-41) {$I=\frac{1}{2}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I will try it when I am at home. Thank you ! !